# Does my app use encryption if has email support?

Tags: ios, app-store

Recently when attempting to publish my first app build to the app store I was prompted with: Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available within Apple’s operating system.) If I use apples built-in email system to email developers does that count as using encryption?

Comment: Yes, it does. So you can select "yes"

Comment: I would argue no, because the built-in email system is running in its own process above your app.